# autosys jil command to make a box success when a job inside is inactive

Tags: conditional-statements, autosys

i have a box a_box and i have one job a_job inside the box. the job a_job runs only from tue to friday and the box runs from tue to sat due to other dependancies. the job a_job will go to inactive on saturday and the box is in running state on saturday. i want to make the box to success with the inactive job automatically. i tried the condition box_success: n(a_job) but this command never seems to be working. Could you kindly help with the jil as to how it has to be framed to make the box to success with an inactive job inside automatically on saturdays

Answer (score 0):

As the box and job has different and independent date condition, it is good to have the job outside the box to resolve the issue. As per my experience, it may not be possible to make the box to success automatically with the inactive job inside the box. We have two options here, either mark the box to success manually once all the other jobs inside the box succeeds or remove the job a from box and made it independent.

Answer (score 0):

Including term_run_time in box jil might be useful in case maximum run time of job is known..